# Horizontal RecyclerView with expandable height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandable

I would like to reproduce this behavior on Android
This is a simple horizontal RecyclerView where all the child items can be expanded with an animation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI323jA67x0

But unfortunately, I don't see how to achieve this with standart recyclerview.

I have had multiple ideas, but I don't see how I can achieve in a correct way.

1) modifying the whole recyclerView heigth at runtime, but I need to mesure a children and give it an height with measured dp ?

2) setting visibility to all children TextViews from Visible to Gone, but seems horrible...

3) ???

Thank a lot for any advice.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?